# Rotation is different after resizing movieclip

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, flash, trigonometry

I am trying to implement transform methods to rotate and resize a movieclip at runtime and I have a problem when recalculating the rotation to follow the mouse.

I have a squared movieclip and a rotator object (a circle) at the right bottom corner of the square where I am listening for mouse events and on mouse move I do this:

```
_rotation  = -(Math.atan2((event.stageX - this.x  ), (event.stageY - this.y ))) * 180/Math.PI;

this.rotation = rotation + 45;//this is because my rotator object is on right,bottom corner
```

this works perfect as long as I don´t modify the width or height of the object but if I do modify then there is a small "jump" on the rotation of the object that I am not able of avoid.

I know this is due event.stageX and even.stageY are different as the rotator object, the one with the mouse listener, has moved after the resize event but no clue how to avoid the "jump".

Please excuse my bad English

Comment: you have to transform mouse coordinates to clip unrotated coordinate system first then compute angle and then rotate (because if you resize with different aspect ratio then original clip then the angles on screen/mouse and on clip will not match)

Comment: Yeah, @Spektre I think you are right, I will try that later and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You need to rotate the object around its center.

```
/**
* Rotates the object based on its center
* Parameters: @obj => the object to rotate
* @ rotation => angle to rotate
* */
public function RotateAroundCenter(obj:Object, rotation:Number):void
   {
        var bound:Rectangle = new Rectangle();
        // get the bounded rectangle of objects
        bound = obj.getRect(this);

        // calculate mid poits
        var midx1:Number = bound.x + bound.width/2;
        var midy1:Number = bound.y + bound.height/2;

        // assign the rotation
        obj.rotation = rotation;

        // assign the previous mid point as (x,y)
        obj.x = midx1;
        obj.y = midy1;

        // get the new bounded rectangle of objects
        bound = obj.getRect(this);

        // calculate new mid points
        var midx2:Number = bound.x + bound.width/2;
        var midy2:Number = bound.y + bound.height/2;

        // calculate differnece between the current mid and (x,y) and subtract
        //it to position the object in the previous bound.
        var diff:Number = midx2 - obj.x;
        obj.x -= diff;
        diff = midy2 - obj.y;
        obj.y -= diff;
}
```

Usage:

```
_rotation  = -(Math.atan2((event.stageX - this.x  ), (event.stageY - this.y ))) * 180/Math.PI;
RotateAroundCenter(this,  rotation + 45);
```

Check this [link](http://subashselvaraj.com/2010/08/20/rotate-around-center-flexas3/)

Comment: I am curious why you didn't use the [Matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html) class for this? This is exactly the kind of task it's there for.